# How to change numpy array based on mask array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mask

I have an array data_set, size:(172800,3) and mask array, size (172800) consists of 1's and 0's. I would like to replace value form data_set array based on values (0 or 1) in mask array by the value defined by me: ex : [0,0,0] or [128,16,128].

I have tried, "np.placed" function but here the problem is the incorrect size of mask array.

I have also checked the more pythonic way:
data_set[mask]= [0,0,0] it worked fine but for some raison only for 2 first elements.

```
data_set[mask]= [0,0,0]

data_set = np.place(data_set, mask, [0,0,0])
```

My expected output is to change the value of element in data_set matrix to [0,0,0] if the mask value is 1.

ex.

```
data_set = [[134,123,90] , [234,45,65] , [32,233,45]]
mask = [ 1, 0, 1]

output = [[0,0,0] , [234, 45,65] , [0,0,0]]
```

Comment: Try `data_set[mask.astype(bool)] = 0`

Comment: Or `data_set[np.where(mask)] = 0`., `data_set[mask == 1] = 0`.

Comment: thank you. it works with [0,0,0] but what if i need to replace it with other values like ex. [128,16,128]?

Comment: `data_set[mask.astype(bool)] = [128,16,128]`

Comment: great! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When you try to index your data with `mask` numpy assumes you are giving it a list of indices. Use boolean arrays, or convert your mask to a list of indices:

```py
import numpy as np

data_set = np.array([[134,123,90] , [234,45,65] , [32,233,45]])
mask = np.array([1, 0, 1])
val = np.zeros(data_set.shape[1])

data_set[mask.astype(bool),:] = val
# or
data_set[np.where(mask),:] = val
```

The first one converts your array of ints to an array of bools, while the second one creates a list of indexes where the mask is not zero.

You can set `val` to whatever value you need as long as it matches the remaining dimension of the dataset (in this case, `3`).